# Can we use java stream in the below scenario?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class say `Student` that have a field `marks` of type Double. I am creating a `list` of Student objects. Each student object may have `marks` field set to `null` or set with same value in different student objects. I have a problem where I want to return a single student object from this `list` based on below conditions:

1. when all students have same `marks` then return null.
2. else return student that have highest `marks`.

I wonder if there is a better approach using java stream api to get it done. Thank you in advance.

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private Double marks;

    public Double getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(Double marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [marks=" + marks + "]";
    }

    public Student(Double marks) {
        super();
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: With **2**, **1** seems redundant. Why is there a specific check for 2 students?

Comment: what if 2 students out of 5 have the higest mark? return null too?

Comment: @Bentaye if 2 students out of 5 have the highest marks but equals then also we need to return null.

Comment: Can you show your `Student` class?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear, really. 1 and 2 are not related to your comment... So please be more precise.

Comment: @MCEmperor I have added `Student` class.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès suppose we have 3 student objects and all have equal `marks` so it will be a tie in score and hence we need to return null object, else we have to return student object having highest marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Stream`s, you can do it while collecting to `TreeMap` and verifying the `lastEntry` as in:

```
private Student highestMarkUniqueStudent(List<Student> studentList) {
    if(studentList.size() == 0) return null;
    if(studentList.size() == 1) return studentList.get(0);
    TreeMap<Integer, List<Student>> map = new TreeMap<>(studentList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getMarks)));

    List<Student> highestMarkStudents = map.lastEntry().getValue();
    // only one highest or all same marks or more than one with highest mark
    return highestMarkStudents.size() == 1 ? highestMarkStudents.get(0) : null; 
}
```

Comment: I see, IMO it happens rarely and also makes your logis so verbose. so instead of checking `studentList` size drop `if (map.size() <= 1) return null;` statement, beside that you have checked it in this line `highestMarkStudents.size() == 1 ...`. in addition you use this `list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Student::getMarks,
                        TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));` rather than `new TreeMap(list.stream()....);`

Comment: @HadiJ Makes sense, edited the answer for the same return type as of `null`.. for the latter part of `collect` implementation, I had reversed the implementation considering this cleaner, would be great if you could support the suggestion with some useful links over that.

Comment: I think by using that it would be flexible to use a custom comparator. however, your answer is great!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

Indeed by using *TreeMap* you have the highest marks in the first entry. so by checking its value, you can return desire result. if all marks have the same value so the first entry has to value more than one and if you have two or more highest marks then the first entry has still more than one student object in the list.

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<Student>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Student::getMarks,
                    () -> new TreeMap<Integer, List<Student>>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                    Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));

Map.Entry<Integer, List<Student>> firstEntry = map.firstEntry();   
if (firstEntry.getValue().size() <= 1) {
     result = firstEntry.getValue().get(0);
}
```

Comment: since it's about the highest marks and there is [`lastEntry` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60719430/1746118), it shouldn't be this complicated to construct that map

Answer (score 0):

You might not need streams. Sort the list highest mark firsts, if the first 2 are same, return `null`, otherwise return the first student.

```
students.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getMarks).reversed());
boolean firstTwoHaveSameMarks = students.get(0).getMarks().equals(students.get(1).getMarks());
return firstTwoHaveSameMarks ? null : students.get(0);
```

If 2 or more students have the same highest mark, it returns null, otherwise it returns the student.

Comment: As per the OP, if *all* the students have the same mark, then it has to return *null*

Answer (score 0):

You can work with streams, but you'd need a helper object which would be able to collect your data.

The work now either can be done with redution or with collection.

With reduction, you'd do

```
students.stream().reduce(
       new Helper(),
       (helper, student) -> new Helper(helper, student));

class Helper {
    private Student bestStudent = null;
    private boolean different = false;
    public Helper() {
    }
    public Helper(Helper oldHelper, Student newStudent) {
        if (oldHelper.bestStudent == null) {
            bestStudent = newStudent;
        } else if (student.getMark() > oldHelper.bestStudent.getMark()) {
            different = true;
            bestStudent = student;
        } else if (student.getMark() < oldHelper.bestStudent.getMark()) {
            different = true;
        }
    }
    public Student getResult() {
        return different ? bestStudent : null;
    }
}
```

but that creates a new Helper object for every Student.

With collection, we'd do

```
students.stream().collect(Helper::new, Helper::accept, Helper::combine);

class Helper {
    private Student bestStudent = null;
    private boolean different = false;
    public Helper() {
    }
    public void accept(Student newStudent) {
        if (bestStudent == null) {
            bestStudent = newStudent;
        } else if (newStudent.getMark() > bestStudent.getMark()) {
            different = true;
            bestStudent = newStudent;
        } else if (newStudent.getMark() < bestStudent.getMark()) {
            different = true;
        }
    }
    public void combine() (Helper other) {
        if (bestStudent == null) {
            bestStudent = other.bestStudent;
            different = other.different;
        } else if (other.bestStudent != null && other.bestStudent.getMark() > bestStudent.getMark()) {
            different = true;
            bestStudent = other.bestStudent;
        } else if (other.bestStudent != null && other.bestStudent.getMark() < bestStudent.getMark()) {
            different = true;
        }
    }
    public Student getResult() {
        return different ? bestStudent : null;
    }
}
```

(Note: 1. Code not tested, 2. parts of the basic logic taken from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60718489/296974).)